# Applying the T-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, t-test, inference

[image]

So far I have calculated the sample means $\overline{A} = 0.75$ and $\overline{B} = 2.33$. Using these I computed the sample variances: $S_A^2 \approx \frac{28.805}{9} = 3.2005$ and $S_B^2 = \frac{36.081}{9} \approx 4.009$.

After that, I calculated the pooled variance $S^2_{pooled} = \frac{28.805 + 26.081}{18} = 3.6047$. But now I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is the t-test I'm supposed to use this one: $$t = \frac{\overline{x}-\overline{y}}{s_{pooled}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}}$$ How do I proceed?

Thank you in advance for explanations!

Comment: Since your groups are correlated (they patients are essentially the same across A and B), this is a case of Repeated Measure Design. I would suggest you do a a bit more research on the same before proceeding any further.

Comment: The wikipedia article on the t-test lists several types. You appear to have edited your question down so radically that it's been automatically flagged by the system as low quality, which puts it in review to be closed, and I don't see how it can remain open in its current state. You might do better to roll it back and try to actually answer your original question as far as you can yourself.

Comment: I see you've also invalidated an already received answer; as a result I will roll back to a version where the already-existing answer makes sense. You should then improve that question (consistent with the restrictions on self-study questions) as far as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework, some pointers:

You use t-tests outside of regression mainly for three things:

1. Testing the mean of a group of samples against a number, e.g. do French men tend to be larger than 1.7 m.
2. Testing whether two groups differ in some way, e.g. are French men larger than French women?
3. Testing whether two groups differ, if you have a clear one-to-one link of samples of one group to samples of the other group, e.g. are French husbands larger than their wives? Husbands and wives are linked by being married to each other.

For these cases you use the one-sample t-test, the two-sample t-test and the paired t-test respectively. Your questions shows that you still need to determine which of these three scenarios you have.